# tradingview api-interactivebrokers integration with python and ngrok to automate trading

Tags: post, tradingview-api, interactive-brokers

I am trying to establish autotrade by integrating interactivebrokers with tradingview with python and ngrok. I am basically a biologist and have little to no experience in computer languages.

when I try to use the others procedure, I am facing error 501 Unsupported method ('POST').

Could anyone help me with it.

when i get an alert from tradingview, i am facing 501 Unsupported method ('POST'). Does it has to do with the structure of the jason message in the alert?
Any detailed suggestions are welcome :)

struggling from a month now :(

=====================================================

````
from urllib import response
import ibapi
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper 
from datetime import datetime
from ib_insync import *
from sanic import HTTPResponse 

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
     def __init__(self):
         EClient.__init__(self, self) 

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)
app.run()

#Create root
@app.route('/webhook')
async def root(request):
    return response.text('online')

#Listen for signals and execute orders
@app.route('/webhook1', methods=['POST'])
async def webhook(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        await checkIfReconnect()
        #Parse alert data
        alert = request.json
        order = MarketOrder(alert['action'],alert['quantity'],account=app.wrapper.accounts[123])
        #Submit market order
        stock_contract = Stock('NVDA','SMART','USD')
        app.placeOrder(stock_contract,order)
        return HTTPResponse("ok", 200)  #<-- This line added
        
#Reconnect if needed
async def checkIfReconnect():
    if not app.isConnected() or not app.client.isConnected():
        app.disconnect()
        app = IB()
        app.connect('127.0.0.1',7496,clientId=123)

#Run app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Connect to IB
    app = IB()
    app.connect('127.0.0.1',7496,clientId=123)
    app.run(port=5000)```
````

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing two different packages: ibapi and ib_insync. This can potentially cause problems, as these two packages have different approaches and are not designed to work together.

It's highly likely that the issue originates from the structure of your webhook message from TradingView.

I recommend that you investigate the contents of the webhook message through the Ngrok Agent web interface. You should carefully examine both the HTTP header and the body of the HTTP request. The picture I'm about to attach will serve as an example of what to look for. The current problem might be due to an incorrect structure in these areas.

[image: RAW HTTP packet from ngrok web agent interface]